# How to send Background notification to foreground in Angular Firebase to display notification in Angular 9 webapp?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Angular Firebase for push notifications. Everything is working fine with foreground messages but when i added a 'setBackgroundMessageHandler' call in firebasw-messaging-sw.js file to handle background message its getting triggered but I am not sure how to send the notification in app from there or to convert it foreground.

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {

    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    var data = payload.data;

});
```

Can someone help me with this?

I am using Angular 9.

Comment: how to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

setBackgroundMessageHandler is deprecated. Try it with onBackgroundMessage and in the ts file
`_messaging.onBackgroundMessage = _messaging.onBackgroundMessage.bind(_messaging);`

works for me!

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
    import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { FirebaseApp } from "angularfire2";
    import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
    import 'firebase/messaging';  

    @Injectable()
    export class FirebaseService {

    private messaging: firebase.messaging.Messaging; 

    constructor(
    private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging,
    @Inject(FirebaseApp) private _firebaseApp: firebase.app.App) {
    this.messaging = firebase.messaging(this._firebaseApp);
    }

    
   receiveMessage(): void {
    this.messaging.onMessage(payload => {
      // console.error('new Notification received. ', payload); 
        this.currentMessage.next(payload);
        });
      }
    }
```

then declare **FirebaseService** in your component and you can handle notification event by invoking **receiveMessage** method.

Comment: @rajhim of course , at the beginning i get only foreground notification but now i can get both foreground and background also you should provide valid ssl certificate to test this

Comment: while in next tab, is it working foreground notification? im not able to do.. do u have any sample ?

Answer (score 1):

if you're using the Admin SDK or

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send?=
```

you can handle this by simply changing the payload send to fcm.

the following code won't work as there is notification in payload. so remove the notification and will work. this worked for me without any changes in the code.

```
{
    "notification": {
        "title": "Hey there",
        "body": "Subscribe to AMAL MOHAN N youtube channel"
    },
    "to": "your-browser-token",
    "data": {
        "value1": "text",
        "value2": "",
        "value3": "sample3",
        "value4": "sample4"
    }
}
```

instead the following code will work fine,

```
{
    "to": "your-browser-token",
    "data": {
            "value1": "text",
            "value2": "",
            "value3": "sample3",
            "value4": "sample4"
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

To show foreground notification website need SSL certificate. Test that in development run `ng serve --ssl true` then change http://localhost/4200 to https://localhost/4200.

Answer (score 0):

```
**In Firebase.sw.js :**

    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    
    messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
      const channel = new BroadcastChannel('bg-notification');
      channel.postMessage(payload);
    });


**In Angular Component.ts:**

     ngOnInit() {
        this.channel = new window.BroadcastChannel("bg-notification"); 
        this.channel.addEventListener('message' ,this.handleMessage); 
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Here, the background notification was received in the service worker file. I tried many ways to pass the values to the components but failed. Finally, I tried the "BroadcastChannel" method, and it really works in my Angular 15 project.